# How to export/import JSON File from a given DTO array in Angular 6 to local harddrive?

Tags: .net, json, angular, save

I want to add an export/import functionality to my FrontEnd written in Angular 6.

My FrontEnd gets a DTO in JSON format from a .NET API. My plan is to first get a functionality like a "Save As" Button, so the user can store the DTO[] array as a JSON file on his local harddrive.
In second way he should afterwords then be able to have an "Import" Button to load a JSON File from the local harddrive in to a DTO[] array in FrontEnd.

ComponentA where I subscribe my Observable using async pipe:

```
// component.ts
data: Observable<Setting[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.data = this.dataService.fetchData();
}

// component.html
<tr *ngFor="let s of data | async">
```

I couldn't find a good example or hint to retrieve this. The links I went through were always about Javascript isn't allowed to access local harddrive?

I just found the filesaver.js and streamsaver.js for async operations..

So I need a hint/link/basic example or idea to the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general nature of the internet is going to prevent an application from accessing the uses's hard drive. We do have access to Local Storage, which has some pretty large limits.

```
// save
localStorage.setItem('someName', JSON.stringify(someData));
// get
const someData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someName'));
//clear
localStorage.clear();
```

Other than that you are going to have to provide a true download the user has chosen to save. You can in memory change the format of the data and stream that out as `application/octet-stream` you may even want to test just giving the user a JSON file with a new extension of your choice with the content type of `application/octet-stream` **but** this does not guarantee that a browser is not going to use a *smart feature* to detect and display the JSON inline.

*My first approach would be can this be done with local storage, if not, then I would zip the file in memory and just `application/octet-stream` the file. Then later when the user uploads that file I would make sure the file is a reasonable size (not a hack) unzip, and validate that it is my JSON format and then continue.*

Comment: Ok, thanks to the hint with checking the file size at import!
My first intend was creating a blob of type json and then use filesaver to download. I read the limitations of blob size is about 500-800 MiB, which is more than enough for me(file is about 2 MiB)
[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

Comment: Looks like localstorage has limits of about 5 to 10 MBs depending on browser. For now it would work but I guess my file size will grow in future so it is maybe better to not use localstorage..